# ExpandableListView how to implement?

Tags: android

I've searched here and elsewhere, but got no success in my attempts.

I'd like to make an expandable who had to expand some TextView to EditText.

And preferably show this construction with xml.

It would be a possible example?

---

I have also seen the site developer -> http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ExpandableList1.html
However, I can not use this class in another class.
It would be instantiated?
I tried but got no success.
They can help me?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create Custom Expandible. Please have a look on the following links to get good examples on Expandible list view

[ExpandableListView on Android](http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2010/09/expandablelistview-on-android.html)

and

http://android-adda.blogspot.in/2011/06/custom-expandable-listview.html